# How to access JavaScript file from root directory in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to access my files from root like https://localhost:8080/myfile.js
While hitting this url it is giving me 404 error page not found.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript file is placed in one of the subdirectories of your project as described below, it should work out of the box.

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/myfile.js    
src/main/resources/resources/myfile.js    
src/main/resources/static/myfile.js    
src/main/resources/public/myfile.js
```

> Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

```
/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static/
/public/
```

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot